# Convolve a SED with a filter. Is convoluting the mathematical operation?

Tags: spectroscopy, luminosity, photometry, mathematics

I know that in order to get the Flux of a star (or something else) in a particular filter from its SED (luminosity per unit wavelength), I need to convolve the spectrum (SED) with the filter response. Most of the formulas I see to do this are 
$$F_{b}=\dfrac{\int f(\lambda) T_{b}(\lambda)d\lambda}{\int T_{b}(\lambda)d\lambda}\,,$$ 
where $f(\lambda)$ is the SED, and $T_b$ is the filter response in band $b$.

This formula seems very different from a [mathematical convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) that I would write as 
$$f*g(\lambda)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) g(\lambda-x)dx\,.$$

Are these two convolutions the same thing? Or is the "astronomy convolution" a different thing (e.g. [SED Fitter python package](https://sedfitter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/convolution.html))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the flux of an SED through a particular filter, you actually multiply the the SED by the filter's response. Talking about convolution in this context is a bit of a misnomer.

Basically, for each wavelength, you look at what fraction of the light will go through the filter, and you sum up the values you get at those wavelengths. 
The division by $\int T_{b}(\lambda)d\lambda$ is just a normalization term.

Comment: It is a bit of a misnomer, but I suppose the justification is that the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) says that convolution in the time domain equals point-wise multiplication in the frequency domain. And of course spectra & filter responses are in the frequency (or wavelength) domain.

Comment: @PM2Ring I never thought of it that way, but it would make sense !

Comment: @PM2Ring, does this means I should be able to find a $T_b$ defined in time domain?

Additionally, I always need to integrate over frequency/ wavelength in the Fourier space or over time in the time domain (i.e. $\int_{t^*=-\infty}^{t^*=\infty}\int_{t^=-\infty}^{t=\infty}f(t)T_b(t^*-t)dtdt^*$), right?

Comment: I don't know about the physical relevance of switching to time domain for an SED...

Comment: Thank you. I was just trying to reason further why is this operation called "convolution" in astronomy.

Comment: @PM2Ring could you please confirm your suggestion? The convolution theorem says indeed that convolution in one domain (either time or frequency) is point-wise multiplication in the other.  However, the equation in the OP is not just a point-wise multiplication, but an integral which sort of looks like a convolution with a slight deviation. Can somebody please help with this?